# CoronaSDK Touch Events

Tags: ios, lua, coronasdk

Currently creating a game with Corona SDK is it possible to have an image and when it is clicked it displays 3 images and once one them 3 images are clicked the score increases by 1. Also Im only a beginner at coding , this is a new language to me. Thanks.

```
local CButton = display.newImage("+5.jpg" , 100 , 600)
CButton.alpha = 0.5
CButton.name = "CButton"

local CButtonLabel = display.newText( { text = "", x = 0, y = 0, fontSize = 28 } )
CButtonLabel:setTextColor( 0 ) ; CButtonLabel.x = 100 ; CButtonLabel.y = 45

local function touchCListener( event )

local object = event.target
print( event.target.name.." TOUCH on the '"..event.phase.."' Phase!" )

local ChordCOne = display.newImage("+5.jpg", 900,300)

local ChordCTwo = display.newImage("+5.jpg", 1000,300)

local ChordCThree = display.newImage("+5.jpg", 1100,300)


end


--add "touch" listener -- LABEL IS FOR TESTING!

CButton:addEventListener( "touch", touchCListener)

ChordCOne:addEventListener( "touch", updateScore)

CButtonLabel.text = "touch"
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, new DisplayObjects can be created in a listener function and listeners can be added to those objects as well.

In your code, you have not added the DisplayObjects created in your listener to any GroupObject (such as `scene.view`), which will give unexpected results.

Since the variables pointing to the newly created DisplayObjects (`ChordCOne`, etc.) are `local` to the function where they are instantiated, you cannot call `addEventListener()` on them outside the function.  You should add the listener when they are created.

Also, the `updateScore()` listener function isn't defined anywhere. Make sure `updateScore` is not nil when and wherever you give it as an argument to `addEventListener()`.